# Hive QL - Subset rows with keys in another table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to subset all rows of TableA with key that appears in TableB.

TableA -

```
Idn   X  Y ...
 12   *  *
 13   *  *
 14   *  *
```

TableB -

```
Idn   A B C ...
 12   * * *
 12   * * *
 14   * * *
```

I want to select all elements in TableA with key appearing in TableB.

The following SQL query doesn't work in Hive -

```
select * from TableA where Idn in (select distinct Idn from TableB) a;
```

Is there any other way I can do it?

Can it be done in a single query?

Note that neither table need not be unique in the Idn.

Comment: Actually this eliminates the intermediate table - ``select a.* from tablea a inner join (select distinct idn from tableb) b on a.idn=b.idn``. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like a [SEMI JOIN](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins) should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA LEFT SEMI JOIN TableB on (TableA.Idn = TableB.Idn)
```

LEFT SEMI JOIN implements the uncorrelated IN/EXISTS subquery semantics in an efficient way. As of Hive 0.13 the IN/NOT IN/EXISTS/NOT EXISTS operators are supported using subqueries so most of these JOINs don't have to be performed manually anymore. The restrictions of using LEFT SEMI JOIN is that the right-hand-side table should only be referenced in the join condition (ON-clause), but not in WHERE- or SELECT-clauses etc.

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I wanted. I can comment that this needed only 1 Map-Reduce job, while the equivalent query ``SELECT a.* FROM TableA a INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Idn FROM TableB) b on a.Idn=b.Idn`` needed 2. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers :) Yes, you are right, in the MapReduce job for regular inner joins, mappers run on both tables, emitting out records from that need to be joined by evaluating any UDFs in the query and filtering out any records based on the where clause hence the more jobs.